# GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request - failedPrecondition

Tags: gmail-api

I am trying to get started with the Gmail API. My aim is to send emails from my Gmail account from an application (in Google terms service account). I have been stuck with the following error message for some time. :

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Bad Request",
    "reason" : "failedPrecondition"
  } ],
  "message" : "Bad Request"
}
```

Before posting this question, I have searched Google and Stackoverflow. I found that I needed to 
create an organisation because I only want to use the application internally. To create the organisation, I needed to create my own domain (in the .de TLD) and register this with Google. Google also wanted an email address in this domain of mine, which I  then provided. 
I then set up all possible scopes for Gmail, both on the OAuth concent screen and in the Google cloud admin security page, as suggested by some of the Stackoverflow answers. I have also set domain-wide delegation, as also recommended. In summary, as far as I can see, I have taken all necessary steps as recommended by various questions and answers.
In my code (see below), I have inserted a `credential.refreshToken();` statement, to force an earlier access to OAuth routines. This helped me to solve an earlier problem with Gmail scopes. It is worth noting here, that the call to `GoogleCredential.fromStream()` creates a credential with no scopes. A further call to `credential.createScoped()` is necessary to initialise the scopes to get through OAuth.
My first attempt to use Gmail was to try to send a simple email. This did not work (with the same error as above). I therefore decided to use a simpler test - reading the labels on the Gmail account. Again, this did not work with the error message shown above. As my code below shows, I was uncertain exactly what values to use for the *appName* and the *emailId* required by the Gmail APIs. I have therefore iterated over all possible values that came to mind. 
I have the following questions:

- Is the Gmail API trying to send Emails over the email address  that is registered with my domain (for discussion purposes `ds.de` and `ds@ds.de`, to use a fictitious example), rather than my Gmail account? If this is the case, then I am probably trying to do something impossible.
- Is there any way of getting more error information from Google about what the *failedPrecondition* is?
- Is it possible that I have missed something in setting up my service account? As far as I can see from the various Stackoverflow answers, I have done everything correctly, but perhaps I have missed a small but vital step. 
   
  Since posting this question, I have found the following question and answer:
  [nodejs gmail failedPrecondition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49092338/nodejs-gmail-failedprecondition) 
  On clicking on the answerer *DaImTo*, I see that he or she is a [Google Developer Expert](https://developers.google.com/community/experts/directory), recognized by Google. I think therefore, that I have the answer to my question - what I am trying to do is impossible!!! Pity!

#### Test Code

```
`
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      testOauthService();
   }

   public static void testOauthService() {
      HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT;
      try {
         HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
      } catch (Exception ex) {
         System.out.println("Exception creating HTTPTransport: " + ex.getMessage());
         return;
      }

      final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

      System.out.println("public static void testOauthService () called. ");

      System.out.println("Credentials file is: " + credentialFile.getAbsolutePath());

      if (!credentialFile.exists()) {
         System.err.println("The credentials file " + credentialFile.getAbsolutePath() + " does not exist!");
         return;
      }

      String[] scopeEnums = { GmailScopes.MAIL_GOOGLE_COM, GmailScopes.GMAIL_COMPOSE, GmailScopes.GMAIL_INSERT,
               GmailScopes.GMAIL_LABELS, GmailScopes.GMAIL_METADATA, GmailScopes.GMAIL_MODIFY,
               GmailScopes.GMAIL_READONLY, GmailScopes.GMAIL_SEND, GmailScopes.GMAIL_SETTINGS_BASIC,
               GmailScopes.GMAIL_SETTINGS_SHARING };

      boolean bFound = false;
      String uid = USER_ID;
      for (String appName : APP_NAMES) {
         try {
            System.out.println("App name: " + appName + ", userId = " + uid);
            FileInputStream credentialStream = new FileInputStream(credentialFile);
            GoogleCredential credential;
            credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(credentialStream, HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY);
            credential = credential.createScoped(Arrays.asList(scopeEnums));
            // The following statement is probably not necessary in production. It does however help with diagnosing
            // OAuth problems by forcing an earlier access to OAuth and thus easing later diagnosis.
            credential.refreshToken();
            System.out.println("Token successfully refreshed!");

            Gmail.Builder builder = new Gmail.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential);
            builder.setApplicationName(appName);
            Gmail gmail = builder.build();
            Users users = gmail.users();
            GetProfile getProfile = users.getProfile(uid);
            System.out.println("Profile user id = " + getProfile.getUserId() + ", " + getProfile.toString());

            // Lets try to use some simple Gmail functionality - getting a list of the labels.
            Gmail.Users.Labels labels = users.labels();
            for (String emailId : EMAIL_USER_IDS) {
               System.out.println("Trying labels.list() for email id " + emailId);
               try {
                  Gmail.Users.Labels.List labelList = labels.list(emailId);
                  ListLabelsResponse response = labelList.execute();
                  System.out.println("labelList.response: " + response.toString());
               } catch (Exception ex) {
                  System.out.println("Exception in label listing: " + ex.getClass().getName() + ": " + ex.getMessage());
                  continue;
               }
               System.out.println("Label listing successful with App Name = " + appName + ", User Id = " + uid
                        + ", email id = " + emailId);
               bFound = true;
            }

         } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + ex.getClass().getName() + ": " + ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
            continue;
         }
         if (bFound)
            break;
      }

      System.out.println("public static void testOauthService () finished");
   }
`
```

Comment: I hate to break it to you but Google Developer Experts are [not employed by nor affiliated with Google](https://developers.google.com/community/experts/directory). They generally know their stuff but their word can't be taken as official Google documentation.

Answer (score 0):

- If you want to run simply read the labels in your Gmail inbox, all you have to do is follow the [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java)
- If you want to perform the same through a service account, the obtention of the credentials would be a little different, you need to

  - paste into your working path a `.p12` file the service account credentials,
  - you need to specify the email of the service account in `.setServiceAccountId` and you need to specify the email of the user on whose behalf the service account is expected to act in `.setServiceAccountUser`.
  - If you specify your email - your code will be listing your labels; if you let the service account impersonate any of the other of your Google domain users - the service account can access their labels and emails (provided you enabled the domain wide delegation).

A working sample code:

```
    public static void main(String... args)   throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException
{
    final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();                           
     File pk12=new File("NAMEOFTHEFILE.p12");       
     String serviceAccount="EMAILOFTHESERVICEACCOUNT"; 
     GoogleCredential getCredentials = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
      .setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT)
      .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
      .setServiceAccountId(serviceAccount)
      .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(pk12) 
      .setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPES)
      .setServiceAccountUser("MAILOFTHEUSERTOIMPERSONATE")  
      .build();

        // Build a new authorized API client service.
        Gmail service = new Gmail.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials)
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();
...
```

### Important: You need to give the service account all scopes it needs in the Admin console, as explained in the [Delegating domain-wide authority to the service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) section of the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you ziganotschka, for your suggestions and help. I want to use a service account, because I want to integrate the code into an existing IMAP service. I had already enabled the domain wide service account delegation. I tried your suggestion of adding `setServiceAccountUser(EMAIL_USER)` to the `GoogleCredential.Builder` call. 
Incidentially, if one follows the code in `GoogleCredential` [https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client/blob/master/google-api-client/src/main/java/com/google/api/client/googleapis/auth/oauth2/GoogleCredential.java],
it is possible to use a JSON file rather than a p12 file (as in your example).

Your help enabled me to analyse my problem(s) further. If I used my original Gmail email address as my EMAIL_USER, then I got a `TokenResponseException: 401 Unauthorized response`. This, original, GMail address 
is naturally NOT registered in the domain that I needed to create to create my service account, and there does not seem to be an easy way (that I can find after much googling) to register it in my domain (lets call it *ds.de*). 
If I use the in my domain registered email address (lets say *ds@ds.de*) and try to send an email, then I get the error `GoogleJsonResponseException Mail service not enabled`, which is perhaps not surprising, as my domain is
external to the Google world. 
I then thought of creating a new domain in the Google world for test purposes - but Google does not allow this, as I live in Germany and one can only create a domain through Google if one lives in specific countries (https://support.google.com/domains/answer/4639612?hl=en) - and Germany is not one of them!

I come to the conclusion that, because I live in Germany, I cannot use the Gmail API. I will therefore stick with using IMAP in my service application (which has been running successfully for several years). I just wanted to upgrade to the latest standards!

 
If, though, you have any more suggestions, I would be delighted to try them.